# Block Access to URL in ASP.NET and C# in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config

I am trying to block specific URL to all users in `web.config` file in my ASP.NET webforms, but it is not working. Note that my admin table is located in SQL Server (`admin_login_tbl`). I have tried below code in `web.config` file but all users/admin page is denied. Can you please look into this code what is the issue.

```
<location path="adminitemlist.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles ="admin" />
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: are you using Forms authentication? Perhaps show your code where you get the users role

Comment: Yes using forms authentication and admin data stored in SQL Server table

Comment: show your code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: shown above in web.config.

Comment: what about the code that authenticated the user from the sql? Is that returning the correct values?

Comment: Yes it is returning correct values

Answer (score 0):

what location is this web config file?

You cannot have more then one web.config file in the SAME folder. And that ALSO includes the root folder. (so, you can't just drop in a extra web config file, and expect/assume that BOTH .config files will be used - they will not!!

So, only ONE file.

As a general rule, if I have say a site admin page, and want to secure to a given group of users? (given group of Roles)

Then I will move all of the web pages to a sub folder, and drop in that web.config file.

Now, you CAN add such security to specific pages in the MAIN web config file if the page in question is ALSO in the root file.

However, since that web.config file is a HUGE mess and will have boatloads of config stuff and a gazillion other things?

Then you would DO VERY well to move such pages out into a folder.

But, you can specify such pages, and you have to include the path name to that sub folder.

Say like this in the main web.config file:

[image]

But, I VERY much tend to avoid the main web.config file for this purpose.

So, in above, I would add the web.config file to folder Test4 like this:

[image]

And thus the simple web.config file in that folder becomes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
       <allow roles ="admin" />
       <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So, not only does above mean no hard coded path name, and you don't need one?

Well, if you copy, or move or change the location of such pages, then the above will continue to work.

So in summary:
ONLY ONE .config file allowed per folder.

You CAN add and secure a folder in the main web.config file if you include the path name. But, I think one should VERY much leave that main config file alone - it always a huge hairy ball of a configuration anyway.

Comment: dear, i have only one web.config file

Comment: Ok, is that in the root folder, or are we talking about a specific folder. But the above will and should work assuming this is in the main web.config file. So make sure you place that inside of the existing web.config file, and inside before the "<system.web>" section starts.

Comment: hello we are talking about the root folder

Comment: I have put the code as below now not able to access even as admin role  <location path="adminitemlist.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
   
   <authorization>
    <allow roles ="admin" />
    <deny users="*" />
   </authorization>
   
  </system.web>
  
 </location>

Comment: I am logging in using admin role. But do i need to write any code inside adminitemlist.aspx?

Comment: You have to include the path name to the one given page - else of course you lock out everyone. As I stated, in near all cases, to define secuirty for a given set of web pages, then create a new folder, drop in/create pages in that folder, and you can then drop in a web.config file to secure that page. But, to secure ONE page in the main root folder (which is beyond silly and dumb and stupid on your part), then you have to include the location path so you don't wind up securing everything in that folder, (which in this case is the root folder ). But, no code is required.

Comment: As my screen shot shows, you place that authorization tag BEFORE the web.config seciton as I did in my screen shot. (just a another REALLY great reason why attempting to secure individual pages in the root and messing around in web config AS I posted out is a hairy ball of markup - and it is REALLY easy to mess this up - just as you did. That's again why I suggested to move such pages to their own folder. But, as my screen cap shows, you don't place that auth tag inside of web.confg. And is your user role called "admin" or "siteadmin" or whatever - you have to use correct role name.

Comment: Thanks you for such detailed explanation. Ok i will try separate folder for admin. But please fyi that i have admin table in ms sql server that has admin user and password along with role.

Comment: Role table and membership in roles is a seperate table assuming you are using a security provider. If you are rolling your own security system and not using a security provider? Then IIS has no means to know what roles from the roles table each user has membership in, and hence using built-in security of IIS not going to work for you. I assume that role security is working for existing sub folders right? What security provider have you setup and are using here? I assume that each user can have membership in many of the roles you defined, right?

Comment: Dear i am using session variable for logging in if will try to share a code and send a link to u by evening.

Comment: Ok, if you rolled your own security system, then using IIS and web.config not going to work, since IIS as a web server will have ZERO clue about some "roll your own" security system you cooked up. This is VERY much why it near always better to use a supported security provider, since then your using IIS for security, and you don't have to write code for each page to prevent use of such pages. If you just created your OWN logon system, and not using a IIS supported security provider? Then of course using web.config will not work, since it has no idea or means to know what security used.

Comment: Hello please find my website code download, which will clarify further. Since i am a beginner you can expect many mistakes. But website is working fine including login and logout only issue that  URL restriction is not applied    https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3ee4a03a2236ce2eb45c4b4f0f6d9eaa20220818160432/018311a9b22ceb2c9177c2470125fe0a20220818160455/cc4393

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247373/discussion-between-aza01-and-albert-d-kallal).